# rails show checkbox value checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show `check_box_tag` with checked value if the value of `branch_id` contains in `user_branches`. I have user controller like this:

```
def edit
  @user_branches = @user.user_branches
  @branch = Branch.all
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and I have view like this :

```
<% @branch.each do |branch| %>
  <ul>
    <%= check_box_tag 'branch_ids[]', branch.id, (:checked if @user_branches.map{|x|x.branch_id}.include?(branch.id)) %>
    <%= branch.name -%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
<% @branch.each do |branch| %>
  <ul>
    <%= check_box_tag 'branch_ids[]', branch.id, @user_branches.map(&:branch_id).include?(branch.id) %>
    <%= branch.name -%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```